# Sending data to multiple sockets at exact same time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sockets

I'm want to design a ruby / rails solution to send out to several listening sockets on a local lan at the exact same time.  I want the receiving servers to receive the message at exact same time / or millisecond second level.

What is the best strategy that I can use that will effectively allow the receiving socket to receive it at the exact same time.  Naturally my requirements are extremely time sensitive.

I'm basing some of my research / design on the two following articles:

- http://onestepback.org/index.cgi/Tech/Ruby/MulticastingInRuby.red
- http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_socket_programming.htm

Now currently I'm working on a TCP solution and not UDP because of it's guaranteed delivery.  Also, was going to stand up ready connected connections to all outbound ports.  Then iterate over each connection and send the minimal packet of data.

Recently, I'm looking at multicasting now and possibly reverting back to a UDP approach with a return a passive response, but ensure the message was sent back either via UDP / TCP.

Note - The new guy syndrome here with sockets.

Is it better to just use UDP and send a broad packet spam to the entire subnet without guaranteed immediate delivery?

Answer (score 0):

Is this really a time sensitive component? If it's truly down to the microsecond level then you may want to ensure its implemented close to native functions on the hardware. That being said a TCP ACK should be faster than a UDP send and software response.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say millisecond range. I'll correct the question.  Each listening socket on the LAN (no WAN, internet) needs to receive the data within say, a cross section of 0.01 and 0.001 range.  The server listening side needs to kick of process at the same time, run the process and report back when done.